# Xcode quiting unexpectedly

Tags: xcode

I'm getting an error Xcode 6.3.1 quit unexpectedly whenever Xcode is opened. This was working fine till last night. I have tried restart system but didn't worked. Reinstalling won't be feasible approach since I have downloaded simulator and documentations..

```
Process:         Xcode [1002]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.2 (6776)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6776000000000000~11
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 811890240
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [286]
Responsible:     Xcode [1002]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2016-01-07 14:28:32.142 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F1507)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  4F4E9F72-50D5-A7A3-9513-6D05474ADF7E


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6C131e
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6760/DVTFoundation/Utilities/DVTLocale.m:192
Details:  (rootLang) should not be nil.
Object:   <DVTLocale: 0x7fcdf85378c0>
Method:   -rootLanguage
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fcdf340dac0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

Comment: Not that I know much about Xcode, but that looks to me like it wants you to set a root language.

Answer (score 1):

Try disable "Source Control". Go to Xcode > Preferences, "Source Control" tab and uncheck "Enable Source Control". Reboot your machine and see if it works better. The background is that there are know issues caused by source control in earlier Xcode versions which cause crashes.